# use of buffer object at appendReplaccement () method of Matcher class

Tags: java, regex

```
public Matcher appendReplacement(StringBuffer sb, String replacement)
```

Here why `appenedReplacement()` method should use Buffer object and why we don't use input 
string instead off it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you pass `String` instead of `StringBuffer` and perform append operation on it then the to get the result you must have to retrun that String, because String is immutable so any opertaion performed on it create new String and the method who called `appenedReplacement()` contins the refrence of old actual string.

`StringBuffer` provides you the functionality to append string without changing the reference. So any operation performed on StringBuffer remains even if you not retrn the resultant `String`.

[Matcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement%28java.lang.StringBuffer,%20java.lang.String%29) 
[StringBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) 
[String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

Comment: Thanks. But after rewriting a string, is the actual reference change?

Answer (score 1):

`appendReplacement()` method performs the following actions:

> It reads characters from the input sequence, starting at the append
>   position, and appends them to the given string buffer. It stops after
>   reading the last character preceding the previous match, that is, the
>   character at index start() - 1.
>
> It appends the given replacement string to the string buffer.
>
> It sets the append position of this matcher to the index of the last
>   character matched, plus one, that is, to end().

[Matcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement%28java.lang.StringBuffer,%20java.lang.String%29)

> This method is intended to be used in a loop together with the
>   appendTail and find methods. The following code, for example, writes
>   one dog two dogs in the yard to the standard-output stream:

```
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile("cat");
 Matcher m = p.matcher("one cat two cats in the yard");
 StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
 while (m.find()) {
     m.appendReplacement(sb, "dog");
 }
 m.appendTail(sb);
 System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

As `String` class does not have any `append()` function thats why `StringBuffer` is used in `appendReplacement()` function.

Comment: Thanks but it wasn't my question. I know how and why we use it, I just want to know instead off using buffer object, can't we rewrite the input string sequence? If we can, we won't have to use appendTail() method. Is there any method which can directly rewrite the input sequence?